# Observing late binding call in assembler for virtual function in C++

Tags: c++, assembly

```
file.cpp
#include <iostream>
class Base {
public:
  virtual  void f(int a ){}
};
 class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void f( int a ){ }
};
 
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Derived obj; 
    Base& ref = obj;
    ref.f(777);
    return 0;
}
```

The code was generated by using: g++ -S file.cpp is:

```
    .file   "cp.cpp"
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string "Base::f()\n"
    .section    .text._ZN4Base1fEi,"axG",@progbits,_ZN4Base1fEi,comdat
    .align 2
    .p2align 4,,15
    .weak   _ZN4Base1fEi
    .type   _ZN4Base1fEi, @function
_ZN4Base1fEi:
.LFB1006:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    $10, %edx
    movl    $.LC0, %esi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    jmp _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1006:
    .size   _ZN4Base1fEi, .-_ZN4Base1fEi
    .section    .rodata.str1.1
.LC1:
    .string "Derived::f()\n"
    .section    .text._ZN7Derived1fEi,"axG",@progbits,_ZN7Derived1fEi,comdat
    .align 2
    .p2align 4,,15
    .weak   _ZN7Derived1fEi
    .type   _ZN7Derived1fEi, @function
_ZN7Derived1fEi:
.LFB1007:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    $13, %edx
    movl    $.LC1, %esi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    jmp _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1007:
    .size   _ZN7Derived1fEi, .-_ZN7Derived1fEi
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1008:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $24, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    movl    $777, %esi
    movq    %rsp, %rdi
    movq    $_ZTV7Derived+16, (%rsp)
    call    _ZN7Derived1fEi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $24, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1008:
    .size   main, .-main
    .p2align 4,,15
    .type   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, @function
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
.LFB1019:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    $_ZStL8__ioinit, %edi
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
    movl    $__dso_handle, %edx
    movl    $_ZStL8__ioinit, %esi
    movl    $_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev, %edi
    addq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    jmp __cxa_atexit
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1019:
    .size   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, .-_GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .section    .ctors,"aw",@progbits
    .align 8
    .quad   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .weak   _ZTV7Derived
    .section    .rodata._ZTV7Derived,"aG",@progbits,_ZTV7Derived,comdat
    .align 16
    .type   _ZTV7Derived, @object
    .size   _ZTV7Derived, 24
_ZTV7Derived:
    .quad   0
    .quad   _ZTI7Derived
    .quad   _ZN7Derived1fEi
    .local  _ZStL8__ioinit
    .comm   _ZStL8__ioinit,1,1
    .weak   _ZTI7Derived
    .section    .rodata._ZTI7Derived,"aG",@progbits,_ZTI7Derived,comdat
    .align 16
    .type   _ZTI7Derived, @object
    .size   _ZTI7Derived, 24
_ZTI7Derived:
    .quad   _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE+16
    .quad   _ZTS7Derived
    .quad   _ZTI4Base
    .weak   _ZTS7Derived
    .section    .rodata._ZTS7Derived,"aG",@progbits,_ZTS7Derived,comdat
    .type   _ZTS7Derived, @object
    .size   _ZTS7Derived, 9
_ZTS7Derived:
    .string "7Derived"
    .weak   _ZTI4Base
    .section    .rodata._ZTI4Base,"aG",@progbits,_ZTI4Base,comdat
    .align 16
    .type   _ZTI4Base, @object
    .size   _ZTI4Base, 16
_ZTI4Base:
    .quad   _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE+16
    .quad   _ZTS4Base
    .weak   _ZTS4Base
    .section    .rodata._ZTS4Base,"aG",@progbits,_ZTS4Base,comdat
    .type   _ZTS4Base, @object
    .size   _ZTS4Base, 6
_ZTS4Base:
    .string "4Base"
    .weakref    _ZL20__gthrw_pthread_oncePiPFvvE,pthread_once
    .weakref    _ZL27__gthrw_pthread_getspecificj,pthread_getspecific
    .weakref    _ZL27__gthrw_pthread_setspecificjPKv,pthread_setspecific
    .weakref    _ZL22__gthrw_pthread_createPmPK14pthread_attr_tPFPvS3_ES3_,pthread_create
    .weakref    _ZL20__gthrw_pthread_joinmPPv,pthread_join
    .weakref    _ZL21__gthrw_pthread_equalmm,pthread_equal
    .weakref    _ZL20__gthrw_pthread_selfv,pthread_self
    .weakref    _ZL22__gthrw_pthread_detachm,pthread_detach
    .weakref    _ZL22__gthrw_pthread_cancelm,pthread_cancel
    .weakref    _ZL19__gthrw_sched_yieldv,sched_yield
    .weakref    _ZL26__gthrw_pthread_mutex_lockP15pthread_mutex_t,pthread_mutex_lock
    .weakref    _ZL29__gthrw_pthread_mutex_trylockP15pthread_mutex_t,pthread_mutex_trylock
    .weakref    _ZL31__gthrw_pthread_mutex_timedlockP15pthread_mutex_tPK8timespec,pthread_mutex_timedlock
    .weakref    _ZL28__gthrw_pthread_mutex_unlockP15pthread_mutex_t,pthread_mutex_unlock
    .weakref    _ZL26__gthrw_pthread_mutex_initP15pthread_mutex_tPK19pthread_mutexattr_t,pthread_mutex_init
    .weakref    _ZL29__gthrw_pthread_mutex_destroyP15pthread_mutex_t,pthread_mutex_destroy
    .weakref    _ZL30__gthrw_pthread_cond_broadcastP14pthread_cond_t,pthread_cond_broadcast
    .weakref    _ZL27__gthrw_pthread_cond_signalP14pthread_cond_t,pthread_cond_signal
    .weakref    _ZL25__gthrw_pthread_cond_waitP14pthread_cond_tP15pthread_mutex_t,pthread_cond_wait
    .weakref    _ZL30__gthrw_pthread_cond_timedwaitP14pthread_cond_tP15pthread_mutex_tPK8timespec,pthread_cond_timedwait
    .weakref    _ZL28__gthrw_pthread_cond_destroyP14pthread_cond_t,pthread_cond_destroy
    .weakref    _ZL26__gthrw_pthread_key_createPjPFvPvE,pthread_key_create
    .weakref    _ZL26__gthrw_pthread_key_deletej,pthread_key_delete
    .weakref    _ZL30__gthrw_pthread_mutexattr_initP19pthread_mutexattr_t,pthread_mutexattr_init
    .weakref    _ZL33__gthrw_pthread_mutexattr_settypeP19pthread_mutexattr_ti,pthread_mutexattr_settype
    .weakref    _ZL33__gthrw_pthread_mutexattr_destroyP19pthread_mutexattr_t,pthread_mutexattr_destroy
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I have a problem.
Please show me where held here late binding in assembler code.

Thank in advance for helping.

Comment: *"I'm linking to pastebin.com since the code generated is very long."* Doesn't matter, it belongs ***in*** the question, not just linked. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: Also, you should always use optimization flags such as -O2 when inspecting assembly output. Compilers generate much larger (and, paradoxically, less readable) code without optimization.

Comment: Late binding is between lines 120  (invocation of `Derived` constructor) and 129 (invocation of the `f` virtual method). Note how the virtual method is not invoked by (mangled) name, but by a pointer obtained from the instance's vtable.

Comment: As a side note, most of the junk in your assembly code comes from including <iostream> and the global/static stuff in there. Since you are not using IOStreams, drop it. It would make the question clearer and more concise.

Comment: (My comment and line numbers apply to the original code on pastebin.)

Answer (score 3):

There's no actual "late binding" in your compiled code. It ended up being purely conceptual. The compiler was smart enough to figure out at compile time that this call should be dispatched to `Derived::f`. It generated code that calls `Derived::f` directly (internal name `_ZN7Derived1fEi`)

If you want to see actual late binding, you need to come up with a less obvious code. A good idea would be to make the dynamic type of the object dependent on a run-time value (like a `rand()` call). Something along the lines of

```
Base objb;
Derived objd; 
Base& ref = rand() % 2 == 0 ? objb : objd;
ref.f(777);
```

Comment: A better way to ensure late binding is moving the creation of the object into a different compilation unit. That way you really deprive the optimizer of the information what the runtime type of the object is.

Answer (score 3):

Because the compiler can figure out what is going on, there is no late binding here, instead the call is made directly here:

```
movq    $_ZTV7Derived+16, (%rsp)
call    _ZN7Derived1fEi
```

This is something that compilers have been able to do for some time, and the latest versions even do a lot of analysis to try to determine the binding when it's much less obvious.

Edit (back home from work). If we edit the code a little bit, like this:

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual  void f(int a ){}
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void f( int a ){ }
}; 

extern Derived& MakeObject();

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Base& ref = MakeObject();
    ref.f(777);
    return 0;
}
```

and then compile the code, we get this (from `clang++ -O2 -S virt.cpp`):

```
main:
    pushq   %rax
    callq   _Z10MakeObjectv
    movq    (%rax), %rcx
    movl    $777, %esi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   *(%rcx)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rdx
    retq
```

Here `%rcx` is the address of the virtual function, and `%rax` contains the `this` value - which is then put in `%rdi` which is the first argument. `%esi` is the second argument.

Or, to see more what is going on, we can look at the LLVM IR (Intermediate Representation):

```
define i32 @main(i32 %argc, i8** nocapture readnone %argv) #0 {
entry:
  %call = tail call %class.Derived* @_Z10MakeObjectv()
  %0 = getelementptr inbounds %class.Derived* %call, i64 0, i32 0
  %1 = bitcast %class.Derived* %call to void (%class.Base*, i32)***
  %vtable = load void (%class.Base*, i32)*** %1, align 8, !tbaa !1
  %2 = load void (%class.Base*, i32)** %vtable, align 8
  tail call void %2(%class.Base* %0, i32 777)
  ret i32 0
}
```

Here you can see `%2` being called after being loaded from `%vtable`, which in turn is the result of a `getelementptr` (which is LLVM's way to describe how to find stuff in structures or arrays, which internally the vtable is). It derives `%1` from the `%call` and a `bitcast` (which is essentially what `reinterpret_cast` turns into - because we return a `Derived&` object, we need to change it into a `base&` (which is the same as `Base*` internally in the compiler).

I like LLVM/Clang for this sort of thing, because the LLVM IR is [once you understand it] a bit less cryptic and more "explainative" than the final assembler code - for example a `getelementptr` typically just turns into some combination of add and/or multiply operations [or, in this case, disappears completely, because we're fetching at offset zero], which is less obvious why they are there.

However, g++ also gives the same output:

```
main:
    subq    $8, %rsp
    call    _Z10MakeObjectv
    movq    (%rax), %rdx
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movl    $777, %esi
    call    *(%rdx)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    ret
```

And for reference, here's the vtable for derived:

_ZTV7Derived:
    .quad   0
    .quad   _ZTI7Derived
    .quad   _ZN7Derived1fEi

Note that the vtable is loaded at with:

```
movq    $_ZTV7Derived+16, anobject(%rip)
ret
```

so the *(%rcx) does point at the function `ZN7Derived1fEi`.